# Random fetch request of https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/011908231648370/ww.js in my AMP page

Tags: javascript, amp-html

In my AMP page i found a random fetch request to https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/011908231648370/ww.js.

I am not making this call in my project and now i am having problem because of this. As i found on other articles source map files are use to beautify minified files and this file is asking for source map file at this address http://localhost:2253/ww.js.map which is 404 as i don't have any source map file in my project.

Any suggestions what is this file is all about?

Comment: Possibly a Web Worker based of it's ww.js name. I wouldn't worry about it trying to get source map it's common. Source maps create a map from these compressed asset files back to the source files. This source map allows you to debug and view the source code of your compressed assets, as if you were actually working with the original CSS and Javascript source code.

Comment: i know its not a big deal but the problem is continuous 404 hit on my server.